Equivalence of Finding the Minimum Triangle in a General and Tripartite Graph
I found the following problem in a textbook:
$\textbf{Minimum Triangle}$
Given a weighted directed graph $G = (V, E, w)$ with $|V| = n$ and edge weights $w : E \to \{ -n^c, \ldots, n^c \}$ for some $c > 0$, determine the minimum weighted triangle, that is, determine
$ \min_{(i,j,k)} w(i, j) + w(j, k) + w(k, i)$ , where $(i,j,k)$ (where $i \neq j, j \neq k, i \neq k$) form a triangle.
In the textbook it is claimed that without loss of generality, we assume that $G$ has $3$ parts $I,J,K$ with no edges within them, and the edges going from $I$ to $J$ , from $J$ to $K$ and from $I$ to $K$, i.e., we may assume $G$ is tripartite.
However, I fail to reason why we may assume this. What am I missing?

Let $G(V, E)$ be a graph. You can build a tripartite graph $G'(I, J, K, E')$ with $I=\{i_v, v\in V\}$, $J=\{j_v, v\in V\}$, $K=\{k_v, v\in V\}$ and $E'=\{i_uj_v, j_uk_v, k_uj_v, uv\in E\}$.
We easily check that the triangles in $G$ are in a 1 to 3 mapping with the triangles of $G'$, so the problem of finding a minimal triangle is equivalent in the two graphs.
